# Weakly stationary AR process

Tags: statistics, time-series, stationary-processes

I have the following AR(2) process:
$$Y_t=Y_{t-1}-0.5Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t,$$
where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise with $0$ expectation and variance equal to $1$.
Is this procecss weakly stationary?

In order to check if it is weakly stationary I should check that

1. $\mathbb E(Y_t)$ is independent from $t$
2. $var(Y_t)$ is independent from $t$
3. $cov (Y_t, Y_{t+k})=0$ for every $t, k: k\neq 0$

Using the first two conditions I just proved that if the process is weakly stationary then $\mathbb E(Y_t)=0$ and $var (Y_t)=\frac{1}{0.025}$ but I don't know how to check if the process is weakly stationary. Could someone help me?

Comment: Find the roots of the lag polynomial ($1-L^1+0.5L^2$). The process is stationary if these roots lie outside of the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this a condition for the weak stationarity or for the strong stationarity? Could you suggest me a book in which they explain these arguments about ARMA processes? Sorry, but I am new in statistics. Thank you again.